# MySQL Count query with Group By not returning anything

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand why this query in MySQL does not return any result at all whereas I think it should be returning one row with 0 as the column value

```
select count(ps.id) as totalcount 
from tblpresi ps
inner join users_staging.tbluser u on u.id = ps.userid
where ps.id = 3678
group by ps.id
```

The same query without the "Group By" works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are selecting only 1 ps.id then you don't need to group by it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I think I was trying to make up the minimal query for my question here. Normally, instead of "ps.id = 3678" I have some other where conditions which sometimes dont return any rows.  I just used this for the sake of this question. Sorry, should have mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you expect 1 row with zero count, I assume there is no ps.id of 3678.

If you group-by on an empty result-set, there can be no groups. The group by doesn't "know" about the where-clause, it's only looking through the result-set.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't return that, since your query does not returns results at all (probably there is no ps.id = 3678, or your inner join rules out every row in the result set).

If you change your query to:

```
select count(1) as totalcount 
  from tblpresi ps
 inner join users_staging.tbluser u on u.id = ps.userid
 where ps.id = 3678
 group by ps.id
```

You will get one row with `0`.

Do keep in mind that **if** your `ps.id` is unique in the result set (I don't know if that `inner join` you have will return multiple rows with the same `ps.id`) your `group by` clause is not necessary.

Comment: So how to rewrite the query to be able to get the desired result?

Comment: The above query does not return one row with 0. I am on version 5.1.50 if that makes a difference?